# TPL Tasks stop for SQL Execution

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am trying to process three SQL sprocs that take about 15 minutes each. They're run independently but will be combined at the end. I am using tasks to try and do in parallel (going to try Parrallel.foreach now), but the first SQL that gets hit causes whatever task had not completed to stop and wait, defeating the purpose.

In the code below, I changed to ASYNC execute non query to see if that helped (it didn't) originally it was a regular command.ExecuteNonQuery() - same result

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection()
{
    connection.Open();
    var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        TrackerInfo("T1 started");
        var t = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQueryAsync("Sproc1", connection, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        t.Wait();
        TrackerInfo("T1 completed"); 
    });
    var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        TrackerInfo("T2 started");
        var t = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQueryAsync("Sproc2", connection, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        t.Wait();
        TrackerInfo("T2 completed"); 
    });
    var task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        TrackerInfo("T3 started");
        var t = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQueryAsync("Sproc3", connection, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        t.Wait();
        TrackerInfo("T3 completed"); 
    });
```

I then call them all here:

```
      Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);
```

Which does work, except that all the tasks will stop when they hit their respective SQL execution and pick up when it finishes.

Am I missing something?

Edit - 
The comments below explain why this is happening. But no one posted an answer (yet).

Comment: what do you mean *precisely* when you say "all the tasks will stop when they hit their respective SQL execution" ? what are you looking at? what do you see, and what did you *expect* to see?

Comment: Well for one thing you're using the same SqlConnection instance for all three threads.  Each separate thread should use its own connection.

Comment: @RogerN indeed - at the moment I'm actually surprised it even works, since `SqlConnection` makes no claim of thread safety

Comment: The tasks will run, when they get to the SQL portion they all stop where they are and wait for it to complete before continuing where they were; when it completes, all the tasks continue. @RogerN that would be a problem since they use temp tables. OK, time to rethink it.

Comment: @TonyBasallo the temp tables are not the point. `SqlConnection` itself is not thread-safe. Anything could happen.

Comment: @Tony a single connection is a single TDS stream and a single SPID; TDS does allow pipelining, but a SPID can only be doing one thing at a time.

Comment: You are issuing 3 ThreadPool thread to sit around for 15 minutes while the queries execute in the DB. why use Task.Factory.StartNew? why not execute all ExecuteNonQueryAsync one after the other (as they are async, they will return immediatly) and then await them all with Task.WhenAll?

Comment: I suggest changing it from using a temp table to using a real table. To emulate a temp table you could have a stored proc you run before and after the processes to create and drop the table. Doing it this way would allow you to use three separate connections using the same table and eliminate the temp table problem and would allow the processes to execute asynchronously. Cheers, Z

Comment: @usr The temp tables are only available for the current open connection; the temp tables for this process (as currently written) wouldnt be available if separate connections were used. Again, just a change if new connections are needed

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov there's a few more things that happen as part of the task, it's not just the one query that executes

Comment: @zugzwang that seems to be the way this is going.